# Nuget '2.0.20180607160057-jenkins' is not a valid version string

Tags: nuget, version, push

I have a scripted NuGet push that refuses to push my NuGet package:

```
"%NUGET%" push *.nupkg -Source "%NUGETREPO%"
```

The error I encounter is:

```
'2.0.20180607160057-jenkins' is not a valid version string.
Parametername: value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While writing the question I dug down the rabbit hole to an obvious end.

The relevant implementation is here
[https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/ ... /src/Core/SemanticVersion.cs](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/blob/2.13/src/Core/SemanticVersion.cs)

```
^(?<Version>\d+(\s*\.\s*\d+){0,3})(?<Release>-[a-z][0-9a-z-]*)?$
^(?<Version>\d+(\.\d+){2})(?<Release>-[a-z][0-9a-z-]*)?$
```

When I feed `2.0.20180607160057-jenkins` into an [online Regex Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester)
The string passes both regex tests. The online regex even allows me to toggle `Ignore Case` and `Explicit Capture`.

The next deeper level is in

```
Version.TryParse(match.Groups["Version"].Value, out versionValue)
```

The `System.Version.TryParse` is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.tryparse).
No Version can be smaller than `0` or bigger than `Int32.MaxValue`.
So this particular failure boils down to

```
2147483647 < 20180607160057
```

fairly intuitive actually - and I need a different scheme to generate my patch level for nuget.